# How do I make comments on questions & answers?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, comments

Just joined the site.  This is probably a foolish question, but I see lots of comments on people's questions and answers, but no button with which I can add a comment of my own.  I see a way to *answer*, but not a way to comment.  What am I missing that other people are not? (I've hunted unsuccessfully for an answer on the site.)

Answer (score 1):

You need a [50 reputation](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) to write comments. As you gain more reputation, you are allowed to do more things on Stack Exchange sites. Remember that an upvote on a question increases your score by 5 and an answer, by 10. So, keep writing good questions and answers and you will be able to participate more effectively on the site!

Comment: OK, thanks for the assistance.  But meanwhile it means that stuff that should go in a comment has to be put in an answer instead (or left unwritten).  I'm not too sure that makes sense...

Comment: ...and oddly enough, *here* I seem able to make comments.

Comment: @pensator It's not odd: *"you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you’ve asked, even with 1 rep."* :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello pensator and welcome to the Linguistics SE site!

I suppose this is the first SE site you sign up to, so I hope you'll have a good experience with us. Like Otavio Macedo said, you need **50 reputation** for comments.

If you need further info (in the future), you can check your privileges in two ways:

1. Go to the [FAQ](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq) on the main site and scroll down until you read "[What is reputation?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)". There you'll see what are the "stages" you'll go through as you earn reputation.
2. If you hover the cursor over your name on the Main site, a drop-down window will appear. Click on "Privileges" and you'll see what you can or cannot do (yet).

   [image]

   You can also access this page by adding `/privileges` to any SE site address.

   You should find a page with a list on the right, where you can see your progress. When a privilege reaches 100%, it'll mean you have that privilege.

Answer (score -1):

> But meanwhile it means that stuff that should go in a comment has to
>   be put in an answer instead (or left unwritten). I'm not too sure that
>   makes sense...

Yeah, for me it's kind of weird too.. But I think they put that in order to avoid spam. In my experience, your options seem to be just not write it, write it as an answer then immediately flag it so that admins can convert to comment, or (if the issue you want to comment require admin action) flag the question and say what you want to say

Comment: I don't think that's the best way to deal with the problem. We're not supposed to do that kind of work. It can happen once, but it shouldn't be the "usual practice". :P

Comment: I know. I mean, in case you *really* want to comment it :P

Comment: Ah ok. Just stating it to avoid receiving n+ flags tonight. :P :D

Comment: yeah, good thinking, @Alenanno :P